# Julia: breaking number into different digits

Tags: julia

I am interested in writing a function to convert a number to words in Julia. Such as `f(1234)` return to `"one thousand two hundred and thirty-four"`.

I am getting held up on figuring out how to extract each digit and turn it back into a number. The following works, but it is pretty ugly. Thanks

```
x = 123456789
digits = split("$x","")
intx = zeros(length(digits))
for i=1:length(digits) intx[i]=int(digits[i]) end
intx
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

How about the [digits](http://docs.julialang.org/en/latest/stdlib/base/#Base.digits) function in Base?

```
In  [23]: x = 123456789

Out [23]: 123456789

In  [24]: digits(x)

Out [24]: 9-element Array{Int64,1}:
 9
 8
 7
 6
 5
 4
 3
 2
 1
```

Answer (score 7):

How about this:

```
x = 123456789
digits = Int[]  # Empty array of Ints
while x != 0
    rem = x % 10  # Modulo division - get last digit
    push!(digits, rem)
    x = div(x,10)  # Integer division - drop last digit
end
println(digits)  # [9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1]
```

To do it in the style you were doing it (which you probably shouldn't do), you can do

```
x = 123456789
digits = [int(string(c)) for c in string(x)]
println(digits)  # {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9}
```

Where `c in string(x)` iterates over the characters of the string, so `c::Char`. `int(c)` would give us the ASCII chracter code, so we need to change it back to a string then convert to integer.

Comment: Enumerate only shows 1 dimensional indexes. Is there a way to get N or more indexes in a vector you can use to index another array with N or more sized indexes (ei. Arr[[7,23,4]...]) , using enumerate or some other base function. Does the object in the array have no meta data that includes its index in the array in which it exists?

Comment: @JamesBeezho could you create a new question? Hard to answer in a comment